# Moving List using List Template Item Content Issue

Tags: list, list-template

I have 2 sites called Site A and Site B. I need to transfer a list from Site A to Site B. What I did is save it as List Template(Including the items) and I upload it to Site B. But when I created a list to recreate it. All the dates column is wrong and I can't open the items in the list

Here is the Error I get.

[image]

Note that Site A list is working fine and Site B where the new list is getting the error and has a wrong dates.

The image below is the list for the Site B and site A and its wrong dates

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your list contains lookup columns?

Comment: Hi @Vishal no it doesn't. It just compose of single line text, multiple line text, people and groups and choices

Comment: @JunTan you also mentioned about the date columns, can you upload the screenshot for you list ?

Comment: @AkshayRandive please check the image. The time mismatched I don't know why.

Comment: For the list form issue, are you utilizing an InfoPath or otherwise customized form on the source list? Most customizations to list forms will not be saved in a list template. For the time, please check your regional settings on the destination site (site settings > regional settings). You may have a different time zone selected.

Comment: @OrneryWalrus Yes I'm using a Nintex Form. Do you think that is the cause of the issue? And changing the regional setting fixed the mismatched time. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you check the correlation id in ULS logs on the server? This should indicate the exact error. The error could be with Nintex form or some other.

Comment: @AhmadZia sorry but I'm really new to sharepoint and I don't know where the ULS logs is :(

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online/o365 or on premises?

Comment: @AhmadZia I'm using SharePoint O365

Comment: Yes, I would say the Nintex form is the issue. I would save the form, revert the source list back to the original list forms, then save your template and provision the destination list, and then apply the Nintex form to it. Glad the time issue is resolved!

Comment: @OrneryWalrus yes the Nintex form is the issue. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, its not easy to check ULS logs for O365. You need to contact Microsoft support with the correlation id. This may take some days for them to come back. Meanwhile i would recommend to do these two steps to isolate the issue.

1. Create a new list "ListA" (keep just one "Title" column) with Nintex form.
2. Create a new list "ListB", keep just one "Title" column and no Nintex form. Keep default SharePoint forms.

Save them as template and create on other site. Now see which of them works? This would determine if the issue is with Nintex.

If both of them work then the issue could be in one of the fields - though very unlikely.